# Ionic iOS session issue

Tags: ios, session, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic Framework. My app requires logging in.

The problem is that on iOS, whenever the user forces quit app, the session is lost so that the user has to log in again.

How do I preserve session in this case?

(Same session logic is applied on Android app and it works perfectly fine, so I assume that it has something to do with force quit in iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to preserve session after adding the code below in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
   NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    NSData *cookieData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cookies];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cookieData forKey:@"Cookies"];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    NSData *cookiesData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Cookies"];
    if ( [cookiesData length] )
    {
        NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookiesData];
        for ( NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies )
            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```